# How to get all string values for UITextField in UITableViews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I am trying to create an array with all values that are presented in textfields that are inserted in a tableview. I am currently using the following code:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        editedValues.append(textField.text!)
}

@IBAction 
func saveEditedProfile(_ sender: Any) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(profileNameTextField.text, forKey: "Name")
    print(editedValues)
    for i in 1...ProfileDataOptions().myProfileValues.count-1{
        UserDefaults.standard.set("\(i)", forKey: ProfileDataOptions().myProfileValues[i])
    }
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

However, the print function only returns an array of the values that were edited, and I want it to return the values for each textfield, including the unedited ones. How do I create this array?

Comment: So there are more than one textfield if yes then do you also want the values of other textfield which are not edited?

Comment: Yes to both of those

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the append editedValues when user presses Enter on the texField. Use

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool{

    editedValues.append(textField.text!)
    return true
}
```

**Edited**

```
var editedValue = ""
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        editedValue = textField.text!
    }
```

Now in

```
@IBAction func saveEditedProfile(_ sender: Any) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(profileNameTextField.text, forKey: "Name")
        editedValues.append(editedValue)
        for i in 1...ProfileDataOptions().myProfileValues.count-1{
            UserDefaults.standard.set("\(i)", forKey: ProfileDataOptions().myProfileValues[i])
        }
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true
        )
    }
```

Comment: I want the values to be returned when I hit a button (that is what the second function is for)

Comment: This still only gets the values of the textfields that are edited

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving the text on the button click then the simplest way of doing it will be getting the values on click. If your row and section is at 0th position. you can change according to your row or section number.
For Ex:-

```
@IBAction func saveEditedProfile(_ sender: Any) {
    let index = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    let cell: XYZTableCell = self.myTableView.cellForRow(at: index) as! XYZTableCell

    editedValues.append(cell.profileNameTextField.text ?? "")
    editedValues.append(cell.abcTextfield.text ?? "")

    UserDefaults.standard.set(profileNameTextField.text, forKey: "Name")
    editedValues.append(editedValue)

    for i in 1...ProfileDataOptions().myProfileValues.count-1
      {
        UserDefaults.standard.set("\(i)", forKey: ProfileDataOptions().myProfileValues[i])
      }
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't save the values that are in the tableview though

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the table value using below function

```
func getTableCellsData() -> [String] {
        //Your Array
        arrData.removeAll()
        for section in 0 ..< self.tblView.numberOfSections {
            for row in 0 ..< self.tblView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: row, section: section)
                let cell = self.tblView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! tblCell
                //You get you cell value
                self.arrData.append(cell.textField.text)
            }
        }
        print(arrData)
        return arrData
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

let newArray = textField.text?.trim.split(separator: " ")

You can use this array and replace your existing array and then reload the tableview!